# Declaration cannot be more available than enclosing scope

Tags: swift, frameworks

A class of mine in my framework has iOS 16 only API dependencies (stored props of PhotoPicker related types)

so I attempted to mark it as available in 16 only:

```
@available(iOSApplicationExtension 16.0, *)
public class EditImageModelPhotoPicker: EditImageModel
{
```

But I get a very descriptive

> Declaration cannot be more available than enclosing scope

from the swift compiler
[image]

What does that supposed to mean and what are the ways out of this?
Deployment target is iOS 15.

UPD: Changing to @available(iOS 16.0, *) seems to have feixed it even though I previosly always had to use @available(iOSApplicationExtension 16.0, *) in frameworks

Comment: On which line does the error appear? None of the lines shown in the screenshot has the error.

Comment: The error itself shows no line. Changing to @available(iOS 16.0, *) seems to have feixed it even though I previosly always had to use @available(iOSApplicationExtension 16.0, *) in frameworks

Comment: `iOSApplicationExtension` is for code that can only use the subset of API available to app extensions such as widgets, notification content extensions, Siri intent handlers etc. Frameworks that are linked with an app and an extension would typically use it, but if the framework is only used by app targets then you wouldn’t use it. In your case, I think `PhotoPickerItem` or something else in your class is unavailable to app extensions, causing the error.

Comment: than you @GeoffHackworth. I think that is it, I need to make yet another framework that allows non extension safe APIs such as PhotoPicker

Comment: You can maybe just add another availability constraint to your view model to mark it as unavailable in app extensions: `@available(iOSApplicationExtension, unavailable)`

Answer (score 2):

Change `@available(iOSApplicationExtension 16.0, *)` to just `@available(iOS 16.0, *)`.

Answer (score 1):

Courtesy of
Geoff Hackworth
I ended back then with count'em 2 (two) decorators

```
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
@available(iOSApplicationExtension, unavailable)
```